# Move jira from one server to another

Tags: jira, data-migration

I wonder how to move jira from one server to another. I have problem with attachments which take about 200gb disk space. The question is how should I copy them if jira on the old server must working constantly and the new atachments is still coming. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did almost a similar exercise with a scheduled downtime. Simply copy the latest X months of data to the new server and point the links to the new server. In the background move all other data into the new server.

Answer (score 1):

I would use rsync to do the initial sync of the attachments folder then schedule a cutover for over the weekend if you are a mon-fri type shop or overnight otherwise.

The cutover would exist of shutting down access to the current JIRA, perform a second rsync to pickup any new attachments and a final restore to ensure the data is up to date. That would guarantee nothing would be missed or lost.